# For pandas query is very slow, How to enhancing performance？

Tags: python, pandas

How to quickly find the data that meets the conditions and terminate the subsequent search in advance.Search from right to front until the maximum findlimit of the search.
Expected accuracy <= 0.001s,
Current accuracy >= 0.03s

```
def test_Find(df:pd.DataFrame,findLimit:int=365):  
    success = False
    current = pd.DataFrame()
    start = len(df) -1
    loopCount = 0
    # Compare from back to front
    for i in range(start, -1, -1):
        loopCount += 1
        if loopCount > findLimit:
            return pd.DataFrame()
        current = df.iloc[i]
        success = Find(i, df)
        if success:
            return current
    return pd.DataFrame()
#Whether the last value is greater than the current value
def LastPassCurrent(curi:int, df:pd.DataFrame):
    current = df.iloc[curi]
    last = df.iloc[-1]
    result = last.c > current["c"]

    return result
#  Whether the current residual value is Less than or equal to the current value
def RemainNoPassCurrent(curi:int, df:pd.DataFrame)->bool:
    cur = df.iloc[curi]
    remain = df.iloc[curi+1:-1]
    maxC = remain["c"].max() 
    if np.isnan(maxC):
        maxC = 0
    remainNoPassCurrent = maxC <= cur["c"]
    return remainNoPassCurrent
# Qualified search
def Find(curi, df):   
    current = df.iloc[curi]
    result = (current.a == 8) and  \
    RemainNoPassCurrent(curi, df) and \
    LastPassCurrent(curi, df)
    return result
#test data
dfs = []
for i in range(0, 4000):
    dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(np.arange(365*3).reshape(365,3), columns=list('abc')))
#Test time collection
df = None
for i in range(0, 4000):
    df = dfs[i]
    start_time = time.time()
    data = test_Find(df, 365)
    end_time = time.time()
    result = end_time - start_time
    print(f'loop {i} Empty:{data.empty} time is %.3fs' % result)

#Current testing inefficient time
# loop 0 time is 0.367s ....
```